# Rails if empty, use other value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails application I have a model named "User". User has an column email and a column billing_email. When user creates account he enters the value for user.email. The column billing_email stays empty.

Inside the application I want to use "user.email" if "user.billing_email" is still empty. So unless user has enters value for his "user.billing_email", "user.email" is used.

Can someone point me in the right direction with this? And is the best place to put such code? Inside a helper or inside the user_model itself?

Comment: Have you considered using the `user.email` for the `billing_email` when saving to the db if its not present on creation?

Comment: I did consider this, but I rather keep the billing fields empty if user did not enter this. If storing the user.email as user.billing_email in db, I have problems with other codes like "if user.billing_email is nil".

Comment: If you already want to use the user's regular email as the billing email why would it matter? The checks for `billing_email.nil?` seem unnecessary if you plan on having `billing_email == email`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the getter in your model:

```
def billing_email
  super.blank? ? email : super
end
```

But you'd rather use another method name, or keep the same name but in a decorator for instance.

Comment: Well, this shows indeed the user.email if user.billing_email is blank. But probably I had to explain it bit better: I have a form where user can enter his billing_email. I want to show something as ".... Your default email is now being used for billing...." and app shows a field with user.email. When user clicks on "edit billing email" he can overwrite the current user.email to user.billing_email. If I use above code, the app also change the user.email.

Comment: it wont change the email if you change the billing email

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a new method that checks the presence of the `billing_email` and returns it if present, otherwise it defaults to email.

```
class User
  def valid_email
    billing_email.presence || email
  end
end
```

you can override the `billing_email`

```
class User
  def billing_email
    read_attribute(:billing_email).presence || email
  end
end
```

but I normally avoid this because it can lead to some side effects when the model gets saved or displayed.

In fact, in some cases your code may end-up storing the value of email if `billing_email` is blank, duplicating all the values.

It's better to go with a custom method.